# How to deal with Facebook's Verification requests on flask app

Tags: python, flask, facebook-app-requests

Im setting up a flask app on Heroku to set up web hooks for phishing certificates pulling from Facebook's certificate transparency api. I am trying to get pass facebook's verification requests (facebook sending a GET request asking for hub.challenge) however I do not understand how to give them the required information. Before suggesting I use facebook's prebuilt Heroku app, I am doing this to learn.

I tried looking up more information on GET requests however this hasn't helped me solve this problem.

This is facebook's website on this. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#verification-requests

```
@app.route("/facebook", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
if request.method == 'GET':
    def get_facebook(mode, challenge, verify_token):
        #not sure what to put in here
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the docs, a few pointers:

- You'll receive the request as a `GET`, so you won't need the `'POST'` value in methods
- The values sent from Facebook will be request args, and can be accessed using `request.args.get('e.g.')`
- Facebook is expecting an `int` to be returned, which is up to you to decide what this is.

The result (disclaimer: this is untested!):

```
import datetime
from flask import jsonify

@app.route("/facebook", methods=['GET'])
def get_facebook():
    my_token = 'abc123' # The token you setup on the App dashboard

    if request.args.get('hub.verify_token') == my_token:
        # The token is valid, return the (current datetime as an int)
        # Assuming facebook is expecting a JSON result value
        return jsonify({'hub.challenge': int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())})


    return 'invalid', 403
```

Comment: So you actually return request.args.get('hub.challenge') instead of your own int, makes sense.

Comment: The function is returning a json object with the key 'hub.challenge', and the value of the current datetime (as an int). I'm not sure if this is what Facebook will accept however you'll have to test.